# Rates of convergence of an OLS estimator

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, regression

> I have a linear regression model
>   $$
> y_t=x_t\beta+e_t,\quad t=1,\ldots,N.
> $$
>   Here $x_t$ is non-random and given by $(1,\delta_t t)$ where $\delta_t$ is 1 for odd $t$ and $0$ otherwise. Moreover, $e_t$ is i.i.d. with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
>
> I'm supposed to find the **rates of convergence** (as sample size $\to\infty$) for the OLS estimator $b$ and the estimated variance of $b$.

*Attempt*:  we care about large-sample properties so let's assume for convenience that $N=2k+1$. This allows us to construct the matrices of regressors and error terms
$$
x=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
1&0\\
1&3\\
\vdots&\vdots\\
1&0\\
1&2k+1
\end{pmatrix},\quad
e=\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\\vdots\\e_N\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then,
$$
b-\beta=(x'x)^{-1}x'e=%
\left[\begin{pmatrix}
2k+1&(k+1)^2\\
(k+1)^2&\frac{(k+1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}{3}
\end{pmatrix}\right]^{-1}
\sum_{t=1}^Nx_t'e_t
\\=
\left[\frac{1}{N}\begin{pmatrix}
2k+1&(k+1)^2\\
(k+1)^2&\frac{(k+1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}{3}
\end{pmatrix}\right]^{-1}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^Nx_t'e_t\\
=\left[\frac{1}{2k+1}\begin{pmatrix}
2k+1&(k+1)^2\\
(k+1)^2&\frac{(k+1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}{3}
\end{pmatrix}\right]^{-1}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^Nx_t'e_t.
$$
But how do I now proceed further please?

Comment: What is $u$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry I meant $e$. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$
\begin{align}
\var(b) = \var(\  \underbrace{(x'x)^{-1}x'}_{\begin{smallmatrix} \text{This is constant,} \\ \text{i.e. not random.} \end{smallmatrix}}\ \ y) & = (x'x)^{-1} x' \Big( \var(y)\Big) x (x'x)^{-1} \\[8pt]
& = (x'x)^{-1} x' \Big( \sigma^2 I_{2\times 2}\Big) x (x'x)^{-1} \\[8pt]
& = \sigma^2 (x'x)^{-1} x'x (x'x)^{-1} \\[8pt]
& = \sigma^2 (x'x)^{-1} \in \mathbb R^{2\times 2}.
\end{align}

An estimated variance would then require an estimate of $\sigma^2$.  Often one uses
$$
\frac{\|y - xb\|^2}{n-2}
$$
which is unbiased.  If you make certain assumptions about normality, homeskedasticity, and independence, then the MLE is the same thing but with $n$ rather than $n-2$ in the denominator.

By "rates of convergence" I'm assuming you mean as $k\to\infty$.  Probably one would need to take into account the special form of your $k\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: @ Michael: thank you for your help. Can you help me with the rates of convergence? Despite some familiarity with the usual OLS formulas, I have a hard time thinking about these rates.

Comment: The specified form of you matrix $x$ tells you something about $(x'x)^{-1}$.  My first thought is to get bounds on the variance of $b$ as a function of $k$, and then to apply Chebyshev's inequality.